# Linq query in background - something in PLINQ

Tags: linq, .net-4.0, plinq

Is there something out-of-the-box to run a Linq query in background - maybe based on PLINQ? I have tried a few things, but did not find the proper approach.

I know I can create a background worker to do so, but I am looking for something "I can just use" not requiring to write the whole handling on my own.

Overall picture: I try to keep my WinForm application reactive wile reading the data (via LINQ) and avoid a "blocking" when reading larger amount of data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could spawn a `Task<T>`, and have it wrap your PLINQ query.

PLINQ isn't about creating asynchronous operations (what you want), but rather concurrent processing within a single (blocking) operation.  Instead, you probably want to do something like:

```
Task<IEnumerable<YourType>> task = Task.Factory.StartNew( 
       () => 
       {
           // Use standard LINQ here...
           return myCollection.Where(SomeCriteria);
       }
    );

// When this is completed, do something with the results
task.ContinueWith( t =>
{
    IEnumerable<YourType> results = t.Result;

    // Use results here (on UI thread - no invoke required)

}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Comment: Nice example, also with all details. Especially TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() is noteworthy, because it continues with the original thread and therefor avoids cross thread exceptions when updating the UI (so no InvokeRequired handling is necessary).